# PROMAX DECIPHER hydraulic brake hose replacement

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, maintenance, hydraulic

I have a set of PROMAX Decipher hydraulic brakes and need to replace the hose cable (basically adapt these brakes to another bike and the cables length is longer). I would like to know how to split the cable from the bolt and golden part of the picture.

Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slide the threaded ferrule away from the end and you should see that the gold-colored insert is pressed into the end of the tube.

It pulls out but you may find it difficult to remove since it's barbed.  If needed, carefully split the tubing to remove it.  Heating the assembly to soften the tubing can also make removal easier.

I think it's best NOT to reuse these components as replacements are inexpensive and it's easy to have a leak with your new lines.

Here is what the parts look like:

[image: https://www.atvattg.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=140533]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I got to remove them. Any hint where can i find this replacements?

Comment: Where in the world are you?  The site I found the above photo was in the UK.

Comment: Search for "promax hydraulic brake hose fittings" and you'll see multiple options.

Comment: I am in Finland, but any seller that ships is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have these replacements, but I don’t think will fit the inner part of the brake. Or will it? [image]
In addition, the tube is slightly smaller.

Comment: Those are for Shimano. The design of the seal is radically different. Won’t work safely.

Comment: That’s what I thought. But cannot find the proper replacements of that model